# Extracting the node values in XML with XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML document:

```
<response>
    <result>
        <phone>1233</phone>
        <sys_id>asweyu4</sys_id>
        <link>rft45fgd</link>       
            <!-- Many more in result -->
    </result>

    <!-- Many more result nodes -->

</response>
```

The XML structure is unknown. I am getting XPath for attributes from user.

e.g. inputs are strings like:
    `//response/result/sys_id` , `//response/result/phone`

How can I get these node values for whole XML document by evaluating XPath?

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10465676/3979057) but my xpath is as shown above i.e it does not have `*` or `text()` format.

The [xpath evaluator](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) works perfectly fine with my input format, so is there any way I can achieve the same in java?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult without seeing your code... I'd just evaluate as a NodeList and then call getTextContent() on each node in the result list...

```
String input = "<response><result><phone>1233</phone><sys_id>asweyu4</sys_id><link>rft45fgd</link></result><result><phone>1233</phone><sys_id>another-sysid</sys_id><link>another-link</link></result></response>";
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
        .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("UTF-8")));
XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList node = (NodeList) path.compile("//response/result/sys_id").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < node.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(node.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

Output

```
asweyu4
another-sysid
```

Comment: this gives only first sys_id, I want all the sys_is field's values

Comment: I've updated so it finds "asweyu4" and "another-sysid"... Can you provide an example of your expected output....