# How to retrive recursive element from XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, xpath, xquery

While working on the Xpath Expressions, i stuck in one case, where i have to find out the node, which is dependent on the other node's one element.

Below is the XML example used :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<parent1>
    <child1 id="1">
        <in>Starting1</in>
        <out>connect1</out>
    </child1>
    <child1 id="2">
        <in>connect1</in>
        <out>connect1.1</out>
    </child1>
    <child1 id="3">
        <in>Starting2</in>
        <out>connect2</out>
    </child1>
    <child1 id="4">
        <in>connect1.1</in>
        <out>connect1.2</out>
    </child1>
    <child1 id="5">
        <in>connect1.2</in>
        <out>end1</out>
    </child1>
    <child1 id="6">
        <in>connect2</in>
        <out>connect2.1</out>
    </child1>
    <child1 id="7">
        <in>connect2.1</in>
        <out>connect2.2</out>
    </child1>
    <child1 id="8">
        <in>connect2.2</in>
        <out>open2</out>
    </child1>
</parent1>
```

Desired output is to find out the node, which is having starting point as "Starting" and then travel to another node ( means, out of node is In for other node) & Not ending in "end".

There might be x number of connections between Starting and end.

I have used following xpath expression. But this is limited to 2 level of recursion.

```
//parent1/child1[in=(//parent1/child1[in=(//parent1/child1[in=(//parent1/child1[contains(in,"Starting")]/out)]/out)]/out) and not(contains(out,"end"))]
```

Output :

```
<child1 id="8">
  <in>connect2.2</in>
  <out>open2</out>
</child1>
```

As, i am not sure how many number of connectors could be between the nodes. So, is there any way in XML1.0 to find out recursion?

there is a [duplicate question already in stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463934/how-to-retrieve-node-after-node-of-xml-tree-using-xpath) But, i didn't get the solution from there.

[image]

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. There is no "Starting" point in your input, only "Starting1" and "Starting2". And there could be multiple nodes that meet the criteria. Please state your requirement in a clearer language.

Comment: contains(in,"Starting") tag means, <in> tag text contain "Starting" string in it. you could check xpath expressions for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is not very clear. From the little I think I understand, I believe you will have to do this in two passes.Here's a partial example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="edge-by-in" match="child1" use="in" />
<xsl:key name="edge-by-out" match="child1" use="out" />

<xsl:template match="/parent1">
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:for-each select="child1">
            <edge id="{@id}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="find-start"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="find-end"/>
            </edge>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <!-- process the nodes contained in $first-pass -->
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child1" mode="find-start">
    <xsl:variable name="prev" select="key('edge-by-out', in)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$prev">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$prev" mode="find-start"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <start>
                <xsl:value-of select="in"/>
            </start>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child1" mode="find-end">
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="key('edge-by-in', out)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$next">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$next" mode="find-end"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <end>
                <xsl:value-of select="out"/>
            </end>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply this to your input, the `$first-pass` variable will contain:

```
   <edge id="1">
      <start>Starting1</start>
      <end>end1</end>
   </edge>
   <edge id="2">
      <start>Starting1</start>
      <end>end1</end>
   </edge>
   <edge id="3">
      <start>Starting2</start>
      <end>open2</end>
   </edge>
   <edge id="4">
      <start>Starting1</start>
      <end>end1</end>
   </edge>
   <edge id="5">
      <start>Starting1</start>
      <end>end1</end>
   </edge>
   <edge id="6">
      <start>Starting2</start>
      <end>open2</end>
   </edge>
   <edge id="7">
      <start>Starting2</start>
      <end>open2</end>
   </edge>
   <edge id="8">
      <start>Starting2</start>
      <end>open2</end>
   </edge>
```

Now you can use this to select nodes that have (or don't have) a particular `start` or `end`.

Answer (score 0):

//parent1/child1[contains(in/text(), 'Starting') and not(contains(out/text(), 'end'))]

**UPDATE**

Have a look on image. It returns exactly what you asked for:

[image]

> Desired output is to find out the node, which is having starting point
>   as "Starting" & Not ending in "end".

Could you update your question with your expectations? Maybe with output you expect using XML you added.

Comment: This will return me both elements. because, child1 tag doesn't contains starting & end in single tag. It is connected via reference

Comment: My requirement is to find out last connecting node. Like <out> from child @id=1 element is <in> of child @id=2 element and so on. So, i have to find out the last child1 element, which is not having out as end<n>.

Comment: @rohibatta: Please update you question than. The last element you mentioned does not have 'Starting' as of it. That confused people.

Comment: @rohibatta: you can get last element using this [last()]

Comment: I think you didn't get my question then, I have mentioned recursion in the question that means you have to travel from one node to another to find out <end> element. Same requirement is mentioned in the duplicate question, i have mentioned.

Comment: Yea, I did not get it because I only can read what you wrote :)